# Cant create file inside existing Gist with java org.kohsuke.github API

Tags: java, github-api, gist

I've been working with the org.kohsuke.github Java library for a few days now. My only need for it is to do all things GIST... make them delete them, edit them as well as the different files that exist within gists.

Here's what I CAN do with the library:

Authenticate with a user token.

```
GitHub gitHub = GitHub.connectUsingOAuth(token);
boolean authenticated = gitHub.isCredentialValid();
```

Once authenticated I've been able to...

Pull a list of the users gists:

```
gitHub.getMyself().listGists()
```

Create NEW Gists with a file included:

```
gitHub.createGist()
     .file(filename,contents)
     .description(description)
     .public_(isPublic)
     .create();
```

Delete Gists:

```
gitHub.getGist(gistId).delete();
```

Get a list of files within a given gist:

```
GHGist gist = gitHub.getGist(gistId);
List<String> fileNameList = new ArrayList<>();
for (String filename : gist.getFiles().keySet()) {
     fileNameList.add(filename);
}
```

Though I cannot get the contents of a file this way (it comes back NULL), I have to pull the files' URL and then get the contents of the file like this:

```
String fileContents = "";
GHGistFile file = gitHub.getGist(gistId).getFile(fileName);
try {
     HttpURLConnection conn = gitHub.getConnector().connect(new URL(file.getRawUrl()));
     conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
     InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
     fileContents = IOUtils.toString(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
     is.close();
     }
catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
return fileContents;
```

What I CAN'T seem to do with the API is anything at the gist file level where I need to delete a file, add a file, or update the contents of a file. For example, this code **DOES NOT GENERATE ANY ERRORS**, yet it simply does not work, meaning that the code runs but the file is never created inside the gist:

```
public static void addFileToGist(String filename, String contents, String gistId) {
     GHGist gist = getGist(gistId);
     try{
          gist.update().addFile(filename,contents);
          CustomAlert.showInfo("File Added");
     }
     catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there some other way to do this with the library? Do I need to create new gist files and update them etc. via the HTTPConnector?  If so, I can't seem to figure out HOW to do it and I can't find examples anywhere for gists ... in fact, the internet searches for gist-related documentation or code examples for this library is basically non-existent, so I'm hoping someone out there has experience with it and can point me in the right direction.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Having also posted an issue on the library's GitHub page, I received an answer very quickly.

For anyone in the future having a problem with this library, you have to build it using an OKHttp connection.

So add this to your POM file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
    <version>4.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

then add this to your module-info file:

```
requires okhttp3;
```

Then build the GitHub object like this:

```
GitHub gitHub = new GitHubBuilder().withOAuthToken(token).withConnector(new OkHttpConnector(new OkHttpClient())).build();
```

And all will be well.